# Find Difference between 2 large arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, compare, difference

I have two byte arrays which can be very large, maybe even 700500 values.

`array2` is always larger than `array1`, and it basically contains the same data as in `array1`, but with random additions, for example:

```
int[] array1 = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0};

int[] array2 = {1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 4, 1, 1, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 0, 0};
```

I need to have an `array3`, which needs to have the same size as arrays2. It will show the exact indices where the additions are, so for this example it would be:

```
int[] array3 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

(0 = same as in array1, 1 = different than in arrays1)

I want to have the same result as I get in the application "Beyond Compare":

https://i.ibb.co/yX6YCsp/Diff.jpg

but to get the Indexes of the red marks that you see in the picture, on the right pane.

I need to write it in C#.

Thanks very much for any help on this.

Comment: There are certain cases which could be ambiguous such as the following: `array1 = 2`, `array2 = 22` `array3 = 01` OR `array3 = 10`

Comment: I want to get result as close as possible to what I get in the Beyond Compare application.

Comment: It shows me array3 = 01 for your example.

Comment: I wouldn't expect anybody to do this problem for you. In your example there are at least 30 or so correct answers, probably way more. Just to name a few: `array3 = 000111000011100000110000000000111100000000`, `array3 = 000011010011100000110000000000111100000000`, `array3 = 000011001011100000110000000000111100000000`. Give the problem a try and come back here with a question when you get stuck

Comment: @Erik McKelvey I'm already stuck... the application Beyond Compare knows how to solve this as you can see in the picture that I linked... So I'm looking for an algorithm that will do the same, I have no idea how.

Comment: I will come back in 3 hours and if you still need help I can write you a simple algorithm that will solve this, but it will not give the same output as Beyond Compare. For your example it would give the following output: `array3 = 000011000010011010110000000000111100000000`

Comment: @Erik McKelvey I'm thinking about it for several hours already and I have no idea how to do this! I only knows that it's possible, because I see that the application Beyond Compare does it very well. Also I'm not insisting on writing the function by myself, if there is a ready function that does this I would be very happy to use it! What interests me is just the final result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare each element between the two arrays. If there is a match add a `0` to `array3` and look at the next element in both arrays. If there is no match, add a `1` to `array3` and look at the next element in `array2`. If `array1` has no more elements then keep adding `1` until `array2` has no more elements.

```
int[] array1 = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0};
int[] array2 = {1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 4, 1, 1, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 0, 0};

int index1 = 0;
int index2 = 0;

int[] array3 = new int[array2.Length];
while (index2 < array2.Length)
{
    if (index1 >= array1.Length)
    {
        array3[index2] = 1;
        index2 += 1;
    }
    else if (array1[index1] == array2[index2])
    {
        array3[index2] = 0;
        index1 += 1;
        index2 += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        array3[index2] = 1;
        index2 += 1;
    }
}
foreach (int i in array3)
{
    Console.Write(i.ToString() + " ");
}
```

Output:

`0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: Thanks very much I really appreciate it. I will try it on my data, and I will let you know. It may take a few days. I already see that it's not giving me the same results as Beyond Compare, but maybe I can use it as a base.

Comment: @JohnB Please accept my answer if you found it helpful

Comment: I will accept your answer although I will not have time to test it, I found a solution which is almost perfect for what I need. I save my arrays to Binary files, and then I compare them using the Beyond Compare application. Once I have the Comparison, I save it as an HTML file (in the Beyond Compare menu: Session ---> Hex Compare Report...) , and then I'm using a small C# application that I wrote to extract the data and the adds from the HTML file, because it's format is very easy to understand. So basically I'm using the Beyond Compare to do the Comparison for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [diff algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff), which isn't so easy to do well. I recommend using [Google's DiffMatchPatch library](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch) instead of writing it yourself, but if you want to go to that route, the Wikipedia article should be a good starting point to learn more about that particular rabbit hole.

Comment: I'm not insisting on writing the function by myself, if there is a ready function that does this I would be very happy to use it! What interests me is just the result!

Comment: How do I use this Google's DiffMatchPatch library in C# to give me array3 as in my example?

Comment: How do I download this library and how do I connect it to my application?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JohnB I found a solution which is almost perfect for what I need. I save my arrays to Binary files, and then I compare them using the Beyond Compare application. Once I have the Comparison, I save it as an HTML file (in the Beyond Compare menu: Session ---> Hex Compare Report...) , and then I'm using a small C# application that I wrote to extract the data and the adds from the HTML file, because it's format is very easy to understand. So basically I'm using the Beyond Compare to do the Comparison for me :-)